# What does `asm("" : "+r" (myVar));` mean in AVR-GCC?

Tags: inline-assembly, avr-gcc, atmega

I found following lines in the code of someone else:

```
uint16_t someConstantFactorVariable = ...;
asm("" : "+r" (someConstantFactorVariable));
```

The `someConstantFactorVariable` is inside a frequently used function and I am guessing the author of the code wanted it to have the variable to permanently loaded into a register. Am I right? What is the advantage using this method instead of the `register` keyword in the variable definition?

Comment: The `register` keyword is mostly meaningless these days. But the above "trick", forces the presence of `someConstantFactorVariable` in a register just after the `asm()` because `"+r"` tells `gcc` that it needs to load a register with the value, and assume the value is _changed_ by the `asm` (even though it isn't). Beyond that, no guarantees ... but due to the way the compiler's code generator works, the above is a reasonable way to "hint" the benefits of register presence for a specific variable at a specific time. I would, though, always assess the generated asm for cases like this ...

Comment: @FrankH. Interesting. In avr-gcc you cannot use the `register` keyword with global variables, but you can with local stack variables, so why not just use `register`, since the above code cannot be outside of a function?

Comment: @angelatlarge: the `register` keyword is a hint that must be given at variable declaration time. The `asm()` statement has two advantages over that: First, it can be done way after declaration - just before the code block where you _know_ you'd benefit from having the variable in a register, and/or can give it multiple times at different places within the code. Second, it's more than a hint - it's a direct "do it here and now" command, as the compiler cannot ignore it. The effect is _not_ the same as a _global_ `register` var as `gcc` is free to to re-use the register any time afterwards.